# Python multiprocessing with unpicklable objects

Tags: python, concurrency, process, multiprocessing, pickle

Goal:

- run ~40 huge queries in a db using SQLAlchemy with Threads or Processes, put the corresponding SQLA [ResultProxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy) in a Queue.Queue (being handled by [multiprocessing.Manager](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#managers))
- at the same time, write the results to .csv files with a number of Processes that consume said Queue

Current state:

- QueryThread and WriteThread classes that run the queries and write the data; since the queries take some time to run, there is no significant performance loss due to how the GIL handles threading
- writing the files on the other hand takes forever; in fact, even though the original idea was to run multiple threads of the WriteThread class, the best performance is obtained with a single thread.

Hence the idea to use multiprocessing; I want to be able to write the output concurrently and not be CPU bound but rather I/O bound.

Background aside, here's the issue (which is essentially a design question) - the [multiprocessing library](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.htm) works by pickling objects and then piping the data to other spawned processes; but the ResultProxy objects and shared Queue that I'm trying to use in the WriteWorker Process aren't picklable, which results in the following message (not verbatim, but close enough):

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle object in WriteWorker.start()
```

So the question for you helpful folks is, **any ideas on a potential design pattern or approach that would avoid this issue?** This seems like a simple, classic producer-consumer problem, I imagine the solution is straightforward and I'm just overthinking it

any help or feedback is appreciated! thanks :)

**edit**: here's some relevant snippets of code, let me know if there's any other context I can provide

from the parent class:

```
#init manager and queues
self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
self.query_queue = self.manager.Queue()
self.write_queue = self.manager.Queue()


def _get_data(self):
    #spawn a pool of query processes, and pass them query queue instance
    for i in xrange(self.NUM_QUERY_THREADS):
        qt = QueryWorker.QueryWorker(self.query_queue, self.write_queue, self.config_values, self.args)
        qt.daemon = True
        # qt.setDaemon(True)
        qt.start()

    #populate query queue
    self.parse_sql_queries()

    #spawn a pool of writer processes, and pass them output queue instance
    for i in range(self.NUM_WRITE_THREADS):
        wt = WriteWorker.WriteWorker(self.write_queue, self.output_path, self.WRITE_BUFFER, self.output_dict)
        wt.daemon = True
        # wt.setDaemon(True)
        wt.start()

    #wait on the queues until everything has been processed
    self.query_queue.join()
    self.write_queue.join()
```

and from the QueryWorker class:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        #grabs host from query queue
        query_tupe = self.query_queue.get()
        table =  query_tupe[0]
        query = query_tupe[1]
        query_num = query_tupe[2]
        if query and table:
            #grab connection from pool, run the query
            connection = self.engine.connect()
            print 'Running query #' + str(query_num) + ': ' + table
            try:
                result = connection.execute(query)
            except:
                print 'Error while running query #' + str(query_num) + ': \n\t' + str(query) + '\nError: '  + str(sys.exc_info()[1])

            #place result handle tuple into out queue
            self.out_queue.put((table, result))

        #signals to queue job is done
        self.query_queue.task_done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to avoid using ResultsProxy directly. Instead get the data from the ResultsProxy using cursor.fetchall() or cursor.fetchmany(number_to_fetch) and then pass the data into the multiprocessing queue.

Comment: That works as long as there aren't too many results.  You can also set up a feeder/consumer system where the process with the cursor sends data to the child in chunks and the child requests more when it has finished with the first however many.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I implemented this approach and it's working swimmingly.

I call fetchmany(), populate a chunk_queue with the results of that, and then the consumer processes write based on the queue